# How can I get the decline message by using Docusign API

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi

I have been working with DocuSign API for a while, everything works fine but I cannot get the decline message by using the API when Signer rejects to sign it. I was checking their EnvelopesAPI and their response, cannot find anything about the decline message. Here is the link: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get#EnvelopeRecipients

Does anyone know how can I get the decline message from their API?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please CHECK the best answer to your question. Please upvote all useful answers, including those to other's questions. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

The [EnvelopeRecipients::list](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/list/) method includes the datum as the `declinedReason` attribute in the response.

Also note the `declinedDateTime` and `status` attributes. `status` will be set to `declined`

--that's the **recipient's** status, not the envelope's status.

If you're using v2.1 you can also pull in the declined reason while looking up the envelope (save an API call!) Example call:

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/1234/envelopes/4567?include=recipients
```

The `include=recipients` query parameter will provide the data in the response.